# Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to insert data in mongoDB by html form but I keep getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app=express();
app.set('views',__dirname+'/views');
app.set('view engine','ejs'); //extension of views
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

//mongo db setup in node
var mongo = require('mongodb');
db = new mongo.Db('mydb', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {}), {});

// opening views
app.get('/',function(req, res) {
 res.render('index');
})

// submit post data
app.post('/insert', function(req, res) {
 db.open(function(err, db) {
  db.collection('students', function(err, collection) {
   doc = {
    "sno": req.body.sno,
    "name": req.body.name
   };

   collection.insert(doc, function() {
    res.send("inserted Successfully!");
    db.close();
   });
  });
 });
});

// show data
app.get('/show', function(req, res) {
 db.open(function(err, db) {
  var getStudents = function(db, callback) {
   var cursor = db.collection('students').find();
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
    assert.equal(err, doc);
    if(doc != null) {
     res.send(cursor);
    } else {
     callback();
    }
   });
  };
 });
});

// start Server
var server = app.listen(8081, function() {
 var host = server.address().address
 var port = server.address().port

 console.log("example app listening at http://5s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Comment: You need to be checking for errors on every database call. My guess is that `db.open()` is returning an error, thus the callback argument `db` is `undefined`.  You're also redefined the `db` variable by naming an argument that which could also be a problem.

Comment: jfriend00 is correct. We can't help you very easily here either since you call collection 3 times and we don't know on which line the error is occuring. Some error catching statements are what you need